# Forcing a re-render in React with a new set of items

Tags: reactjs

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  handleDelete(number){
    console.log(number);
    let newQuoteList = this.props.items.filter(function(item){
      return item.id != number;
    });
    console.log(newQuoteList);
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
  render(){
    var listItems = (this.props.items || []).map(item =>
        <ListItem deleteQuote={this.handleDelete.bind(this)} quoteNumber={item.id} key={item.id} value={item.text} />
    );
    return(<ul className="list-group d-none" id={this.props.id}>{listItems}</ul>)
  }
}

class ListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(){
    this.props.deleteQuote(this.props.quoteNumber);
  }
  render(){
    return(
    <li className="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
      {this.props.value}
      <img src="img/delete.webp" onClick={this.handleClick} width="25px"/>
    </li>);
  }
}
```

When the user clicks on the delete image icon in the ListItem component. The handleDelete method is called in the CreateDisplayDiv component. This filters the list items to a new array containing all the list items exepct the one that was clicked. Now i want to force React to re-render the list items. But how can i force react to re-render with the newQuoteList array instead of the listItems array?

Comment: sounds like a great use case for using component state. Where are the `items` coming from? hard to answer without knowing where the data is coming from

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to place the delete funtcion in the parent component and pass it down to this component via props.
The passed down function will be called and it will have it's affect on the state of the parent component.

> ```
> Parent component :
> ```

```
state = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

delete = (id) => {       //// < -- Pass this down as a prop
let newQuoteList = this.state.filter(function(item){
      return item.id != number;
    });
this.setState(newQuoteList);
}
```

> ```
> Child component:
> ```

```
  handleDelete(number){
   this.props.delete(number) // < -- or pass in the ID you want to delete
  }
  render(){
    var listItems = (this.props.items || []).map(item =>
        <ListItem deleteQuote={this.handleDelete.bind(this)} quoteNumber={item.id} key={item.id} value={item.text} />
    );
    return(<ul className="list-group d-none" id={this.props.id}>{listItems}</ul>)
  }
}
```